# Can anyone help in understanding why my Code is giving IllegalMonitorException()?

Tags: java, multithreading

```
class EvenOddPrint {
  public Object lock = "lock";
  public boolean isEven = true;
  public void evenNumber() 
  {
   for(int i = 0; i <= 20; i++) 
     {
      synchronized (lock)
      {
        while (!isEven) {
          try {
            wait();
          } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
          }
        }
        if (i % 2 == 0) {
          System.out.println("Even Thread and my even number is  " + i);
          isEven = false;
          notify();
        }
      }
    }
}

  public void oddNumber() {
    boolean str = false;
    for (int i = 0; i <= 20; i++) {
      synchronized (lock) {
        while (isEven) {
          try {
            wait();
          } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
          }
        }

        if (i % 2 != 0) {
          System.out.println("Odd thread and my Odd number is " + i);
          isEven = true;
          notify();
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

public class ThreadExercisesClass {
  public static void main(String args[]) throws InterruptedException {
    EvenOddPrint e = new EvenOddPrint();
    Thread t1 = new Thread(() -> e.evenNumber());
    Thread t2 = new Thread(() -> e.oddNumber());
    t1.start();
    t2.start();
  }
}
```

I’m trying to print 1 Even and 1 odd number from 0 to 20 using 2 threads, One for Even other for Odd and I need it alternatively, So I tried implementing below code.
1.It worked properly if I use 1. synchronized(this), 2. synchronized(lock) that when lock = new Object()
2.It didn’t work when lock is some String as shown below and giving IllegalMonitorException, I couldn’t understand it properly, Can someone explain it?

**output:**

```
Even Thread and my even number is 0
Odd thread and my Odd number is 1
Exception in thread "Thread-0" java.lang**.IllegalMonitorStateException**: **current thread is not owner**
Exception in thread "Thread-1" java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException: current thread is not owner
```

Comment: synchronizing on `lock` but calling `wait()` (and `notify()`) on `this`, which is NOT `lock`. [JavaDoc]9https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Object.html#wait()): "*This method should only be called by a thread that is the owner of this object's monitor. A thread becomes the owner of the object's monitor in one of three ways:  * By executing a synchronized instance method of that object. * By executing the body of a synchronized statement that synchronizes on the object. * For objects of type Class, by executing a static synchronized method of that class.*"

Comment: Please use [code format](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code) not only for code but also errors and logs.

Comment: Also, initializing your `lock` with a string constant is a bad choice. Since string constants are shared at runtime all other synchronized blocks that happen to synchronize on the same string constant "lock" will synchronize on that same lock. You should use `final Object lock = new Object();` to declare and initialize your lock object.